# Ensure finish time is greater than start time if start/finish dates are equal using jQuery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've got 4 fields - start date (text field using jQuery datepicker), start time (dropdown select), finish date (text field using jQuery datepicker) and finish time (dropdown select).

```
<form id="my_form">

  <label for="start_date">Start Date</label>
  <input type="text" id="start_date" name="start_date" />

  <label for="start_time">Start Time</label>
  <select name="start_time" id="start_time">
    <option value="09:00" >09:00</option>
    <option value="09:30" >09:30</option>
    <option value="10:00" >10:00</option>
    <option value="10:30" >10:30</option>
    <option value="11:00" >11:00</option>
    <option value="11:30" >11:30</option>
    <option value="12:00" >12:00</option>
  </select>

  <label for="finish_date">Finish Date</label>
  <input type="text" id="finish_date" name="finish_date" />

  <label for="finish_time">Finish Time</label>
  <select name="finish_time" id="finish_time">
    <option value="09:00" >09:00</option>
    <option value="09:30" >09:30</option>
    <option value="10:00" >10:00</option>
    <option value="10:30" >10:30</option>
    <option value="11:00" >11:00</option>
    <option value="11:30" >11:30</option>
    <option value="12:00" >12:00</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit" />

</form>
```

I'm using the standard [jQuery Datepicker Widget functions](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) to ensure that the end date is always the same or later than the start date:

```
$( "#start_date" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/y',
    minDate: new Date(),
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#finish_date" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
    }
});
$( "#finish_date" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/y',
    minDate: new Date(),
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#start_date" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
    }
});
```

So my question is, using the [jQuery validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator), how can I add a rule that ensures the end time is greater than (but not equal to) the start time, **if**, the start date and finish date are the same? I'm not even sure where to start on this one and have a blank script at the moment, so any help would be appreciated:

```
$("#my_form").validate({
  rules: {
    start_time: {  }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a significant working start. It will require some modification as to which element(s) you want to set the error on when dates/times are equal or start is less than end, or how you want error to display. The plugin has many options for erorrs.

The core function is :

```
function compareDates() {
    var startDate = $("#start_date").datepicker('getDate');
    var endDate = $("#finish_date").datepicker('getDate');        
    if( !startDate || !endDate){
        return false;
    }

    if(endDate > startDate) {
        return true;

    } else {
        var endTime = endDate.getTime() + $('#finish_time').parseValToNumber();
        var startTime = startDate.getTime() + $('#start_time').parseValToNumber();
        return endTime > startTime;
    }
}
```

This gets used in an `addMethod` to validator:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkDates", function(value, element) {
  /* see function above*/
  return  compareDates() ;
}, "End date/time must be after start");
```

The validator is initialized using:

```
$('#my_form').validate({ 
    rules:{
        start_date:'required', 
        /* arbitrarily used this element  for "checkDates" rule*/
        finish_date:{required:true,checkDates:true},

        finish_time:'required',
        start_time:'required'
    }
});
```

Helper plugin to parse the `select` tag values to a number ( used in `compareDates()` ):

```
/* change the select value to an integer to add to unix time of date from datepicker*/
$.fn.parseValToNumber = function() {
    return parseInt($(this).val().replace(':',''), 10) || 0;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dUe83/1/

This may still have bugs....was hastily put together and not with intent of being a complete off the shelf solution but rather as a significant working starting point.

Comment: This is a massive help! Thank you for the time in putting this together, it's much appreciated.

Comment: I see a few datepicker bugs I'm not used to ... see my `onSelect` code in fiddle. I think this should give you a really solid foundation to tweak though. Also `parseInt()` will return `NaN` if value not set in `select`. Can modify `parseValToNumber` a bit